# make-symbol added unwanted formatting to generated symbols

Tags: lisp, package, common-lisp, symbols

I'm trying to write a function `primeify` that accepts a symbol and returns the symbol with "-prime" appended to it. My desired output is:

```
[1] > (primeify 'y)
Y-PRIME
```

(or `y-prime`, the case isn't the main point here, although it may become relevant later).

Here's my current (erroneous) implementation:

```
(defun primeify (sym)
     (make-symbol (concatenate 'string (string sym) "-prime")))
```

However, `make-symbol` is mangling the output by cluttering it with additional formatting. My output is:

```
[1]> (primeify 'y)
#:|Y-prime|
```

Is there any way to avoid this additional processing done by `make-symbol`, or another function I could use to accomplish this? Is this even possible to accomplish in lisp?

Comment: you need to first upcase the strings

Comment: @VsevolodDyomkin That removed the bars (`||`), but is there any way to remove the `#:`?

Comment: you need to use `intern` if you want a symbol in the current package, instead of uninterned symbol obtained with `make-symbol`

Comment: Above all, it's not `make-symbol` which is adding anything to the symbol's name, it's the Lisp printer that [does](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_acc.htm) [these](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_acca.htm) [things](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_accb.htm) when it prints a symbol. For instance, if you switch to a package that doesn't import your symbol, you'll see `<package-name>:<symbol-name>` (or with :: if it's not exported). The `||` and `\` are used when the name has spaces or lower/mixed case characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your symbol:

```
#:|Y-prime|
```

This is a non-interned symbol. It is in no package. `#:` is in front of the symbol because of that.

It is also a symbol name with mixed case. Because of that it is escaped with vertical bars. Remember, by default symbol names are internally stored in UPPERCASE.

```
(defun primeify (sym)
  (let ((name (concatenate 'string
                           (string sym)
                           "-PRIME")))
    (if (symbol-package sym)
        (intern name (symbol-package sym))
      (make-symbol name))))
```

Above function gives the new symbol the same package as the original symbol has, if any.

```
CL-USER 3 > (primeify 'foo)
FOO-PRIME
NIL

CL-USER 4 > (primeify '#:foo)
#:FOO-PRIME
```

Comment: To get the most consistent behavior under different settings, I 'd use `(string '#:-prime)` or `(symbol-name '#:-prime)` rather than `"-PRIME"`.  Actually, that could happen at read time, so `#.(symbol-name '#:-prime)` would be fine.  Of course, those settings can always change at runtime, so there's no catch-all solution.